# Load balancing multiple PHP sites and JSP sites using Apache Server

Tags: php, tomcat, load-balancing, apache-2.4, jsp

I've been trying for the last couple of days to get this small (i though) scenario working.

Small drawing of my architecture.

`request

         |

     ApacheLB

         |

    |---------|

 Apache1   Apache2

 Tomcat1   Tomcat2`

So far i can get the following to work, either serving my cluster of Apache servers or serving my cluster of Tomcat servers.

The Apache cluster handles PHP sites and uses sticky sessions (works like a charm) and the Tomcat cluster handles JPS sites and this works as well.

What i need is when an request hits my load balancer (ApacheLB) and the host requested begins with say "admin" then the Tomcat cluster takes over other request handles by the Apache cluster.

Both clusters uses handles multiple sites. 
Some examples.

`http://www.company1.com

http://admin.company1.com



http://www.company2.com

http://admin.company2.com`

I´m using Apache 2.4, Tomcat 7, mod_proxy_balancer, all under Windows.

My config.

**Apache LB**


`<VirtualHost *:80>

    Header add Set-Cookie "BALANCEID=lb.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/;" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED`

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
ProxyPass / balancer://lb/ stickysession=BALANCEID nofailover=Off
ProxyPassReverse / http://windows-server1:8009/
ProxyPassReverse / http://windows-server2:8009/

<Proxy balancer://lb>
    BalancerMember http://windows-server1:8009/  route=node1 min=3 max=5
    BalancerMember http://windows-server2:8009/  route=node2
    ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
</Proxy>

<Location /balancer-manager>
    SetHandler balancer-manager
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Balancer Manager"
    AuthUserFile "C:/etc/lb/conf/.htpasswd"
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

</VirtualHost>

**Host**


`<VirtualHost *:8009>

    DocumentRoot "c:/etc/www/test" 
    
ServerName www.company1.com
    
ServerAlias company1.com`

```
<Directory "c:/etc/www/www.company1.com">
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

</VirtualHost>

Any help would be great! 
Thanks!

Best regards
Robert

Comment: Are you looking to route requests to apache OR to tomcat depending upon uri in the request?

Comment: Hi @mahnsc, thats right, depending on URI (host) request should be handled by either the Apache cluster or the Tomcat cluster.

Comment: "Solved" it by creating to load balancer on different ports, handled by DNS.

Comment: If anyone comes up with a better solution im all ears.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments

> Solved" it by creating to load balancer on different ports, handled by DNS.